# best way to select a first sibling's first child in jquery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the first child of a first sibling in jquery but having some trouble getting it right:

```
<tr class="foo"></tr>
<tr>
  <td>
```

I have a handler attached to tr.foo and I want to do something to the td, but I'm not getting the selector right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("tr.foo").next("tr").children("td").first()
```

Check out the [JQuery traversing documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: +1'ed. Was going to post $("tr.foo).next("tr td:first-child") but too lazy to try it.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `tr + tr td` selects the td that has a tr parent that is preceeded by another tr.